# Update mysql field with new string which contains quote marks

Tags: mysql, string, replace, quotation-marks

I cant seem to get this right

I'm trying to replace all instances of a string in a column but because their are special characters I think it's causing it to have no effect.

String I'm trying to replace:

> [{"name":"file/

String I'd like to have instead:

> [{"name":"/var/sites/s/spencercarpenter.co.uk/public_html/shapeshafter/QuickManager/file/

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
UPDATE `spence13_shapeshifteradmin`.`mytable`
 SET `Image` = REPLACE(`Image`, '[{\"name\":\"file\/', 
'[{\"name\":\"\/var\/sites\/s\/spencercooper.co.uk\/public_html\/shapeshafter\/QuickManager\/file\/');
```

Any help much appreciated

Spencer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing your strings without the escape backslash? Your string delimiter is a single quote, so you should not need to escape the double quotes that are within your string. You have:

```
'[{\"name\":\"file/'
```

Try simply:

```
'[{"name":"file/'
```

Comment: Yes I did try this first. I just says no columns affected.

Comment: If no columns were affected, it looks like it can't find your string. Could you run this query? `SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE Image LIKE '%[{"name":"file/%';`

Comment: Yep your right: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: Yet here is the contents of one of the fields pasted straight from the DB: [{"name":"file\/image_tkdluce9.jpg","usrName":nimage.jpg","size":1597626,"type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail":"file\/thimage_jr9jp1tj.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":3773,"searchStr":"image.jpg,!:sStrEnd"}]

Comment: Looking into this further it seems the slashes in the string might be causing the problem. I still can't find an answer. If anyone else could help it would be much appreciated